# Linux waking up after suspend immediately

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management, hibernate

**After none of the solutions on the internet worked**, I'm now asking here for help;

My system will not suspend or hibernate - it wakes up immediately.

I've disabled everything in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` using the command

```
for i in $(cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled | awk '{print $1}'); 
  do 
    echo $i > /proc/acpi/wakeup; 
  done
```

which, predictably did nothing.

I'm not sure exactly how I found this out, but I saw something to do with `network-manager` preventing sleep, however I have no idea what to do with this information. Hence I hope to receive help here.

What is preventing my system from suspending?

### Edit

To answer two important questions:

1. No, Wake on *, including Wake on LAN etc are **not** enabled. I've confirmed this by checking in the BIOS. The option exists and is unchecked.
2. My system is a Dell Inspiron 15 7570 running KUbuntu 22.04 system, running Kernel v 5.15.0-60-generic.
3. The output of `inxi -G` is:

```
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel
Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce MX130] driver: nvidia v: 525.60.13
Device-3: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_HD type: USB
driver: uvcvideo
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce MX130/PCIe/SSE2
v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.60.13
```

Comment: Maybe WoL is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Is it 21.04, or 22.04?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It's actually 22.04.

Comment: What does `inxi -G` say? Might be a GPU driver problem. Add the output to your question, not in the comments

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to provide the information

Comment: Have you explored errors in various system/kernel logs? Reviewing `dmesg`/`journalctl` output may be useful here.

Comment: I have. I've opened my system journal and found a wake request from `Network-Manager`, which unfortunately lead to a dead-end. I've looked for similar issues, but the programs which seem to be causing the issue, also don't seem to be installed. Frankly, this issue is so unlike anything I've come across, I'm asking here to help track it down.

Comment: Can you provide your /etc/default/grub contents? Of special interest are entries concerning acpi or sleep.target Please also provide lines from syslog from where the signal to sleep is given to where the signal to wake again is given.

Comment: Having the same issue with Lenovo Legion. I have wake on lan disabled in BIOS and logs show a wake request from NetworkManager. Ubuntu 23.10.